# MATLAB image patches around multiple coordinates (in vectors) without loops

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have two vectors: `x` and `y` where corresponding rows contain the coordinates of pixels in an image.

I also have a variable `rad` that defines a square window with dimensions `2*rad+1 by 2*rad+1`

If `x` and `y` are scalars,

`patch = img(y - rad : y + rad, x - rad : x + rad);`

produces the `2*rad+1 by 2*rad+1` square window around the point `(y,x)`.

However, as I said above, my `x` and `y` are vectors. Is there a way to get the windows around each coordinate without just looping through the vector.

That is, I want to avoid this:

```
patch = zeros(2*rad+1, 2*rad+1, length(x));
for i = 1 : length(x)
    patch(:,:,i) = img(y(i) - rad : y(i) + rad, x(i) - rad : x(i) + rad);
end
```

Is it possible to do this in a vectorized fashion?

Comment: My bad--my search terms didn't match the other question I guess. On a different note: @rayeng--man, you're prolific in image-processing

Comment: how's it going buddy? Yeah I remember answering this kind of question in the past, which is why I marked it as a duplicate.  I probably should have left you a comment with an explanation of the duplicate :)... in any case, if you look at the answers, a `for` loop is actually the fastest approach... you're pretty solid with using a `for` loop, but there are vectorized implementations available as you can see in the post.  BTW, thanks for the kudos :) Image Processing is what I love to do and I do it everyday.  Good luck!